# Connection Error After Restarting Working Heroku Django App Behind Gunicorn?

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn

We restarted our django app nothing seemed to change but now with every connection we're getting the following error.

What does it mean?  How can I fix it.   I've spent all day trying everything I can think of.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
2 Mar 2017 19:38:52.529  167 <190>1 2017-03-03T01:38:52.278764+00:00 app web.1 - - [2017-03-02 19:38:52 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Socket error processing request.
» 2 Mar 2017 19:38:52.529  128 <190>1 2017-03-03T01:38:52.278767+00:00 app web.1 - - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 93, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 150, in handle_request
    six.reraise(exc_info[0], exc_info[1], exc_info[2])
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 134, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dj_static.py", line 83, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 256, in handle_uncaught_exception
    'request': request
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1185, in error
    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1278, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1288, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1328, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 751, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 129, in emit
    self.send_mail(subject, message, fail_silently=True, html_message=html_message)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 132, in send_mail
    mail.mail_admins(subject, message, *args, connection=self.connection(), **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 98, in mail_admins
    mail.send(fail_silently=fail_silently)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 303, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 58, in open
    self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

It all came down to a malformed key in the redis db.

You will not be able to pull the data or read the key in this spot so just rewrite the key.  Everything worked perfectly after that.